# How to Configure Yubikey 5 for Wondows Hello login

Tags: windows, authentication, webauthn, fido, yubikey

Just added my Yubikey to my Microsoft Account [URL](https://account.live.com/proofs/manage/additional?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=security&client_flight=shhelp,shhidefam) "Passwordless Account" ON. But I don't get prompted for "Touch the USB" :-( I'm only offered PIN or Password after I've locked the PC. Is there something else I have to do? Another setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot currently use a FIDO2 security key for sign in to Windows with a Microsoft consumer account.

The link posted in the comment is for AAD (work/school accounts).

Answer (score 0):

According to yubikey document(https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013708460-Yubico-Login-for-Windows-Configuration-Guide):

> Yubico Login for Windows does not support any of the following:
>
> - Active Directory (AD) managed accounts
> - Azure Active Directory (AAD) managed accounts
> - Microsoft Accounts (MSA)

Comment: Really? I was runing with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/fido2-compatibility